# How can I prove this power set relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Please show me how can I prove this relation:
$$P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cap P(B)$$
I have no idea how to prove these kind of relations that include power sets.

Comment: Do you know what $\mathcal{P}(A)$ represents?

Comment: Yes it represents a power set. a power set is the set of all subsets of S, including the empty set and S itself.

Comment: Do you know how to prove that two sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ are equal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go straight from the definitions.

**Definition.** Let $X$ denote a set. Then $P(X)$ is the unique set such that

$$\forall A(A \in P(X) \leftrightarrow A \subseteq X).$$

**Proposition.** Let $X$ and $Y$ denote sets. Then $$P(X \cap Y) = P(X) \cap P(Y).$$

*Proof.* Let $A$ denote a fixed but arbitrary entity.

Then [TFAE](http://planetmath.org/tfae).

1. $A \in P(X \cap Y)$
2. $A \subseteq X \cap Y$
3. $A \subseteq X$ and $A \subseteq Y$
4. $A \in P(X)$ and $A \in P(Y)$
5. $A \in P(X) \cap P(Y)$

Comment: Doesn't that only prove a subset relationship one way round ?

Comment: @TomCollinge, well all statements in the list are equivalent; hence, we deduce for all entities $A$, we have $A \in P(X \cap Y)$ iff $A \in P(X) \cap P(Y)$. This implies that $P(X \cap Y)$ and $P(X) \cap P(Y)$ are equal, by [extensionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality).

Comment: OK, I hadn't seen the TFAE notation before.

Comment: @TomCollinge, don't know how I could live without my beloved TFAE notation!

Comment: @TomCollinge I'd never seen it before either. I think in this case and in general English usage, you'd do better to write out such abbreviations in full.